# Need Complete Updated Tutorial For Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have WordPress expertise. But I need to learn magento from beginner level. Please give me anyone a proper link where I can get the updated Tutorial For Magento. It should be free of cost.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't get everything to know about Magento for free from one place but you can search through the various site.
Here are the sites I would recommend

[magento-2-create-basic-module-part-1 by qaisarsatti](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-basic-module-part-1/)

[rakeshjesadiya blog](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/category/magento-2/)

[All Video Tutorials - devdocs magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/)

[magento2-tutorial for certification](https://belvg.com/magento2-tutorial)

[magento-2-tutorial-building-a-complete-module](https://www.toptal.com/magento/magento-2-tutorial-building-a-complete-module)

Answer (score 1):

Before starting to learn any platform, you first need to know what are the basic concepts of that platform.

There are plenty of tutorials and blogs which can help you learn Magento 2 easily, but first, you need the basic things which are required before proceeding to the advanced lessons.

Below are some of them:

- Installation of Magento
- Admin Configuration
- The folder structure of Magento themes
- The folder structure of Magento modules
- EAV concept
- Observer, Plugin, and Class Override. Which is better to use in which cases
- Dependency injection and what are its advantages
- Basic commands used in Magento 2
- Steps to create frontend and backend modules
- Steps to create and customize Magento themes

Below is a small list from where you can learn Magento 2:

- [Official Magento 2 documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com)
- [Rakesh Jesadiya's Blog](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/category/magento-2/)
- [Amit Bera's Blog](https://www.amitbera.com/)
- [Tutorials By MagePlaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)
- [Alan Storm's Tutorials](https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/)

Apart from these, you can keep an eye on https://magento.stackexchange.com latest questions for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Has Two Type of Development

1. Module Development
2. Project

**For Module Module Development**

Here Are 
[Tutorials By MagePlaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)

Or if you want Video Tutorials You can Follow

This GUy
[Max Pronko YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxbWGz6h6KNQsi2ughRUV2Q)